# HTML5 Video in iPad not working after DOM changes

Tags: iphone, ios, html, ipad, html5-video

Here is a script that appends the markup for an html5 video to the DOM:

```
document.body.innerHTML = '<video id="video" controls="controls" src="http://mirror.cessen.com/blender.org/peach/trailer/trailer_iphone.m4v" type="video/mp4"></video>';
var el = document.getElementById('video');
document.body.removeChild(el);
document.body.appendChild(el);
```

jsfiddle demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/h8RLS/2/

This works in all browsers tested, except for Safari on iOS.  In iOS, when the HTMLVideoElement is re-appended to the DOM, it is no longer playable.

Has anyone else resolved or encountered this issue?

Answer (score 4):

I don't have an iPad but could reproduce your issue on an iPhone. This seems to be a Webkit error but it can be bypassed easily by changing the `src` attribute of the video - I hope this is sufficient for your scenario. You can see a working demo here:

http://vidhtml5.appspot.com/jsembed.html

This is the code:

```
var el = document.getElementById('video');
el.src= "http://mirror.cessen.com/blender.org/peach/trailer/trailer_iphone.m4v";
el.load();
```

Comment: I don't have an iPhone to test, but this doesn't work on my 4th generation iPad. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nHjRR/

Comment: i have a 4th gen i pad, and the demo link worked fine for me:
http://vidhtml5.appspot.com/jsembed.html

Comment: @AndroidUser The demo didn't remove the video from the DOM, instead it just reset the `src` attribute and called `reload()`. It works on iPad, but I'm afraid it does not reflect the problem produced when the DOM is changed. Please checkout my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nHjRR/) that works on every browsers I tested on Windows and Android but not on an iPad.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I found a workaround using a timer (I'm using jQuery here).

```
var v = $('#videoID');
v.appendTo( $('#toDivID') );
var timer = setInterval( function() {
    clearInterval( timer );
    v[0].load();
    v[0].play();
}, 200 );
```

I've only tested it on the iPad2 on iOS 6.1.

Answer (score -1):

You can include two 'source' tags for your video. I've done this on a site and it works great.

```
<video class="video" controls="controls" id="video1">
<source type="video/mp4" src="demo.mp4">
<source type="video/webm" src="demo.webm">              
</video>
```

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with the issue.

Comment: The question is about changing videos dynamically and not about providing fallback links in case a format doesn't work (which will be the case for WebM on iPad).